# Does CSS Media query load all the referred css?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, media-queries

If i use a CSS Media Query to apply 2 different CSS say desktop.css and mobile.css depending on my max-width, how will this actually work?

Would both the CSS get loaded by the browser always and then apply the actual one at client side OR is the browser intellegient enoough to load only the relevant CSS ?

Comment: Post your media queries. If you resize your browser, the mobile media queries still get applied.

Comment: what if i use device-width instead of width...something which can only happen on either a desktop or mobile but not both...

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're using actual media queries, all of the CSS will be *loaded* on page load, as this is the default behaviour for all browsers that support media queries. It won't apply the CSS until you reach those break-points, or until the rules are met (if you're not using break-point media queries).

If you're using JavaScript that mimics media query behaviour, then that's a different ball game altogether, and depending on how that's been written will depend on whether the CSS is loaded or not.

Code examples will help determine a valid answer here - but from what I can tell, your first statement is correct; the browser will always load all of your CSS, and only apply that which is relevant based on the viewport/device being used at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

It loads all of the CSS and applies it through normal CSS hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how and where you define your CSS. I have [this page](http://cloudfour.com/examples/mediaqueries/image-test/) as a reference for the way images load based on different media queries.

Basically, though, if you load your CSS conditionally based on media queries then it shouldn't load until that media query has been satisfied.

Comment: I thought I had a scenario in which the CSS didn't load (no http request) but I'm not able to get that result. I'll update my answer if I ever find it. Though the page on images is still good.